# Using boost::spirit, how do I require part of a record to be on its own line?

Tags: c++, parsing, boost-spirit, eol, boost-spirit-qi

I have a record parser that throws one of several exceptions to indicate which rule failed.

Front matter:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/classic_position_iterator.hpp>

using namespace boost::spirit;
using namespace boost::spirit::ascii;
using namespace boost::spirit::qi;
using namespace boost::spirit::qi::labels;

using boost::phoenix::function;
using boost::phoenix::ref;
using boost::spirit::qi::eol;
using boost::spirit::qi::fail;
using boost::spirit::qi::lit;
using boost::spirit::qi::on_error;

using BOOST_SPIRIT_CLASSIC_NS::file_position;
using BOOST_SPIRIT_CLASSIC_NS::position_iterator;
```

We use the [`position_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/spirit/classic/doc/position_iterator.html) from [Spirit.Classic](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/spirit/classic/index.html), so the following stream-insertion operator is handy.

```
std::ostream&
operator<<(std::ostream& o, const file_position &fp)
{
  o << fp.file << ": " << fp.line << ',' << fp.column;
  return o;
}
```

The template `err_t` factors out the boilerplate for throwing the exceptions associated with different forms of parse failure.

```
template <typename Exception>
struct err_t {
  template <typename, typename, typename>
  struct result { typedef void type; };

  template <typename Iterator>
  void operator() (info const &what, Iterator errPos, Iterator last) const
  {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << errPos.get_position()
       << ": expecting " << what
       << " near '" << std::string(errPos, last) << "'\n";
    throw Exception(ss.str());
  }
};
```

The exceptions used along with their `err_t` wrappers:

```
class MissingA : public std::runtime_error {
  public: MissingA(const std::string &s) : std::runtime_error(s) {}
};

class MissingB : public std::runtime_error {
  public: MissingB(const std::string &s) : std::runtime_error(s) {}
};

class MissingC : public std::runtime_error {
  public: MissingC(const std::string &s) : std::runtime_error(s) {}
};

function<err_t<MissingA> > const missingA = err_t<MissingA>();
function<err_t<MissingB> > const missingB = err_t<MissingB>();
function<err_t<MissingC> > const missingC = err_t<MissingC>();
function<err_t<std::runtime_error> > const other_error =
  err_t<std::runtime_error>();
```

The grammar looks for simple sequences. Without [`eps`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/quick_reference/qi_parsers/auxiliary.html), the `start` rule fails rather than `a` on an empty input.

```
template <typename Iterator, typename Skipper>
struct my_grammar
  : grammar<Iterator, Skipper>
{
  my_grammar(int &result)
    : my_grammar::base_type(start)
    , result(result)
  {
    a = eps > lit("Header A") > eol;
    b = eps > lit("Header B") > eol;
    c = eps > lit("C:") > int_[ref(result) = _1] > eol;
    start = a > b > c;

    a.name("A");
    b.name("B");
    c.name("C");

    on_error<fail>(start, other_error(_4, _3, _2));
    on_error<fail>(a, missingA(_4, _3, _2));
    on_error<fail>(b, missingB(_4, _3, _2));
    on_error<fail>(c, missingC(_4, _3, _2));
  }

  rule<Iterator, Skipper> start;
  rule<Iterator, Skipper> a;
  rule<Iterator, Skipper> b;
  rule<Iterator, Skipper> c;
  int &result;
};
```

In `my_parse`, we dump the contents of the stream into a `std::string` and use `position_iterator` to track the parse's location.

```
int
my_parse(const std::string &path, std::istream &is)
{
  std::string buf;
  is.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);
  std::copy(std::istream_iterator<char>(is),
            std::istream_iterator<char>(),
            std::back_inserter(buf));

  typedef position_iterator<std::string::const_iterator> itertype;
  typedef my_grammar<itertype, boost::spirit::ascii::space_type> grammar;
  itertype it(buf.begin(), buf.end(), path);
  itertype end;

  int result;
  grammar g(result);

  bool r = phrase_parse(it, end, g, boost::spirit::ascii::space);
  if (r && it == end) {
    std::cerr << "success!\n";
    return result;
  }
  else {
    file_position fpos = it.get_position();
    std::cerr << "parse failed at " << fpos << '\n';
    return -9999;
  }
}
```

Finally, the main program

```
int main()
{
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << "Header A\n"
     << "Header B\n"
     << "C: 3\n";

  int val = my_parse("path", ss);
  std::cout << "val = " << val << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

The code above throws `MissingA`:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'MissingA'
  what():  path: 2,1: expecting  near 'Header B
C: 3
'
```

I thought the skipper might have consumed the newline, but attempting `lexeme[eol]` instead produced the same result.

I must be missing something obvious because this seems one of the most trivial sort of parsers to write. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the skipper eats the newline characters. `lexeme[eol]` doesn't help either because the lexeme directive invokes the skipper before switching to no-skipper mode (see [here](http://boost-spirit.com/home/2010/02/24/parsing-skippers-and-skipping-parsers/) for more details).

In order to avoid skipping newlines, either use a different skipper type, or wrap the `eol` components into `no_skip[eol]`, which is semantically equivalent to `lexeme[]`, except it does not invoke the skipper. Note though, that `no_skip[]` has been added recently only, so it will be available with the next release only (Boost V1.43). But it is in the Boost SVN already (see [here](https://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/directive/no_skip.html) for the preliminary docs).