# How do I parse end-of-line with boost::spirit::qi?

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, eol, boost-spirit-qi

Shouldn't a simple [`eol`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/quick_reference/qi_parsers/auxiliary.html) do the trick?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using boost::spirit::ascii::space;
using boost::spirit::lit;
using boost::spirit::qi::eol;
using boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse;

struct fix : std::unary_function<char, void> {
  fix(std::string &result) : result(result) {}
  void operator() (char c) {
    if      (c == '\n') result += "\\n";
    else if (c == '\r') result += "\\r";
    else                result += c;
  }
  std::string &result;
};

template <typename Parser>
void parse(const std::string &s, const Parser &p) {
  std::string::const_iterator it = s.begin(), end = s.end();
  bool r = phrase_parse(it, end, p, space);
  std::string label;
  fix f(label);
  std::for_each(s.begin(), s.end(), f);
  std::cout << '"' << label << "\":\n" << "  - ";
  if (r && it == end) std::cout << "success!\n";
  else std::cout << "parse failed; r=" << r << '\n';
}

int main() {
  parse("foo",     lit("foo"));
  parse("foo\n",   lit("foo") >> eol);
  parse("foo\r\n", lit("foo") >> eol);
}
```

Output:

```
"foo":
  - success!
"foo\n":
  - parse failed; r=0
"foo\r\n":
  - parse failed; r=0
```

Why do the latter two fail?

---

**Related question:**

[Using boost::spirit, how do I require part of a record to be on its own line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428371/using-boostspirit-how-do-i-require-part-of-a-record-to-be-on-its-own-line)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are using `space` as the skipper for your calls to phrase_parse. This parser matches any character for which `std::isspace` returns true (assuming you're doing ascii based parsing). For this reason the `\r\n` in the input are eaten by your skipper before they can be seen by your `eol` parser.

Comment: Using `phrase_parse(it, end, p, space - eol)` allowed `eol` to succeed. Thanks!

Comment: @GregBacon When I type `space - eol`, I get very weird and long error message.

Comment: @Dilawar See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10469726/85371] for related hints and techniques to change the skipper behaviour