# How can I use the skipper ascii::space WITHOUT skipping eol?

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I have to use boost::spirit for parsing, and I want use phrase_parse function :

```
qi::phrase_parse(str.begin(), str.end(), grammar, ascii::space - qi::eol);
```

But the fourth term (ascii::space - qi::eol), isnt allowed by my compiler.
How can I use the skipper ascii::space WITHOUT skipping eol ?

Comment: What exactly is the problem that the compiler has with `ascii::space - qi::eol`? It'll make a big difference in terms of possible solutions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429485/how-do-i-parse-end-of-line-with-boostspiritqi

Comment: @rhalbersma: But it seems no compilable solution is given there.

Comment: In the "possible duplicate", the solution is ascii::space - eol as a skipper, but "- eol" isnt allowed, thats my problem, I want skip ascii::space but not qi::eol

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The simplest answer is

```
qi::phrase_parse(str.begin(), str.end(), grammar, ascii::blank);
```

Of course, it depends on your grammar too: if it expects a specific skipper class you might need to change that. **See below for a *generic* way to handle that** (although you could just specify `qi::blank_type` for a Grammar that should only accept `qi::blank`).

The sample handles arbitrary skippers too.

#### Other hints

Spirit has several directives that influence the use of skippers:

- [`qi::lexeme`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/directive/lexeme.html)

  will parse the sub-expression regardless of skipper (useful for e.g. string literals in a grammar)
- [`qi::raw`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/directive/raw.html)

  will return the raw source iterator range, meaning that skipped input will be included in the result
- [`qi::no_skip`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/directive/no_skip.html), [`qi::skip`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/directive/skip.html)

  can be used to explicitely change the type of skipper used for the subexpression

#### Recommended reading

The Boost Spirit site has a nice article about things like this

- [Parsing Skippers and Skipping Parsers](http://boost-spirit.com/home/2010/02/24/parsing-skippers-and-skipping-parsers/)

#### Generic sample

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template <typename It, typename Skipper>
    struct parser : qi::grammar<It, Skipper>
{
    parser() : parser::base_type(start)
    {
        start = *qi::int_;
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<It, Skipper> start;
};

template <typename C, typename Skipper>
    void doParse(const C& input, const Skipper& skipper)
{
    auto f(std::begin(input)), l(std::end(input));

    parser<decltype(f), Skipper> p;
    bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f,l,p,skipper);

    if (ok)   
        std::cout << "parse success\n";
}

int main()
{
    const std::string input = "1 2 3 4";
    doParse(input, qi::blank);
    doParse(input, qi::space);
    doParse(input, ~qi::char_("0-9"));
}
```

Comment: +1 exactly what I was looking for to glue together a bunch of mini-parsers (that only handle one line at a time)

Comment: Where does the Skipper go if the rule takes an output type (like `std::string()`)?

Comment: The parenthesis is really important **"(although you could just specify qi::blank_type for a Grammar that should only accept qi::blank)."** Although something in fishy because now I have to change all my grammars to `qi::blank_type` even though the subtokens do not need to know about `eol`. I guess it is because I don't think like a spiriter yet.