# Boost Spirit Qi Attribute Propagation

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I have an issue with a Boost Spirit Qi grammar that is emitting an undesired type, resulting in this compilation error:

```
error C2664: 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::insert(unsigned int,const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::_String_iterator<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>' to 'unsigned int'
```

Here is the grammar that is causing the issue:

```
    qi::rule<Iterator, qi::unused_type()> gr_newline;

            // asmast::label() just contains an identifier struct that is properly emitted from gr_identifier
    qi::rule<Iterator, asmast::label(), skipper<Iterator> > gr_label;

    gr_newline = +( char_('\r')
                   |char_('\n')
                  );
```

This fails:

```
gr_label = gr_identifier
           >> ':'
           > gr_newline;
```

But the following
 all work:

```
// This parses OK
gr_label = gr_identifier
           > gr_newline;

// This also parses OK
gr_label = gr_identifier
           > ':'
           > gr_newline;

    // This also parses OK
    // **Why does this work when parenthesized?**
    gr_label = gr_identifier
           >> (':'
                > skip_grammar.gr_newline
              );

// This also parses OK
gr_label = gr_identifier
           >> omit[':'
                    > gr_newline];
```

**I don't understand why removing the character literal or omit[]ing it "fixes" the problem, but I don't want the grammar to be cluttered with that.**

According the the compound attribute rules for >> and > found [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/quick_reference/compound_attribute_rules.html#spirit.qi.quick_reference.compound_attribute_rules.notation), and character parser attributes [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/char/char.html), gr_label should only emit asmast::label

```
a: A, b: B --> (a >> b): tuple<A, B>
a: A, b: Unused --> (a >> b): A  <---- This one here is the one that should match so far as I understand
a: Unused, b: B --> (a >> b): B
a: Unused, b: Unused --> (a >> b): Unused


 Expression Attribute
 c          unused or if c is a Lazy Argument, the character type returned by invoking it.
```

However, somehow something is polluting the intended attribute, and resulting in the compiler error.

So my questions are where this grammar emits an undesired attribute, and how to get rid of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be because you mix and match `>` and `>>` here.

Though you correctly observe the documented attribute generation rules, what *really* appears to happen is that the `Unused` side is more like `fusion::vector1<qi::unused_type>` (instead of `qi::unused_type`).

> Side note: 
> *This also explains "**Why does this work when parenthesized?**"  - 
>  you are altering the order of expression evaluation (overruling operator precedence)
>  and getting another type.*

You can find out whether my hunch is correct using techniques like e.g. [Detecting the parameter types in a Spirit semantic action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404189/detecting-the-parameter-types-in-a-spirit-semantic-action).

So, the **short answer** is: this is how it works. Whether that is a bug, an omission in the documentation or just a feature is really not constructive to discuss on SO. I refer to the [spirit-general] mailing list (note they also have an active #IRC channel).

---

The **slightly longer** answer is: ***I think there is more to it that you are not showing***.

Two things:

1. The error message quite clearly indicates that it is trying to `insert` a **string *iterator**** where a character (or convertible) was expected. I don't see a connection with any of the code you posted, though I can guess at

   - the use of qi::raw[] somewhere (quite likely)
   - the use of an iterator_pair in one of your ast structs (quite unlikely)
2. I can compile your "problematic" rule specimen just fine embedded in my "mock-up" grammar I built up guessing from the little bits you exposed in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18399896/boost-spirit-qi-expectation).

   - see the full program I used below or see it **[running Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=d710fc2b063fb28c79f15b9c87906b9e-e4c1374605e7ee935e94e8e1e68651e5)** (I also compiled this locally using GCC 4.7.3 and boost 1.53)

> I think maybe you should try to post another question, while showing a [Short Self Contained Correct Example](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you are *really* having.

Be sure to mention the compiler version and version of boost used.

#### Fully Working SSCCE example

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi    = boost::spirit::qi;

namespace asmast
{
    typedef std::string label;
}

template <typename It, typename Skipper = qi::blank_type>
    struct parser : qi::grammar<It, Skipper>
{
    parser() : parser::base_type(start)
    {
        using namespace qi;

        start = lexeme["Func" >> !(alnum | '_')] > function;
        function = gr_identifier
                    >> "{"
                    >> -(
                              gr_instruction
                            | gr_label
                          //| gr_vardecl
                          //| gr_paramdecl
                        ) % eol
                    > "}";

        gr_instruction_names.add("Mov", unused);
        gr_instruction_names.add("Push", unused);
        gr_instruction_names.add("Exit", unused);

        gr_instruction = lexeme [ gr_instruction_names >> !(alnum|"_") ] > gr_operands;
        gr_operands = -(gr_operand % ',');

        gr_identifier = lexeme [ alpha >> *(alnum | '_') ];
        gr_operand    = gr_identifier | gr_string;
        gr_string     = lexeme [ '"' >> *("\"\"" | ~char_("\"")) >> '"' ];

        gr_newline = +( char_('\r')
                       |char_('\n')
                      );

        gr_label = gr_identifier >> ':' > gr_newline;

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((start)(function)(gr_instruction)(gr_operands)(gr_identifier)(gr_operand)(gr_string));
    }

  private:
    qi::symbols<char, qi::unused_type> gr_instruction_names;
    qi::rule<It, Skipper> start, function, gr_instruction, gr_operands, gr_operand, gr_string;
    qi::rule<It, qi::unused_type()> gr_newline;
    qi::rule<It, asmast::label(), Skipper> gr_label, gr_identifier;
};

int main()
{
    typedef boost::spirit::istream_iterator It;
    std::cin.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);
    It f(std::cin), l;

    parser<It, qi::blank_type> p;

    try
    {
        bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f,l,p,qi::blank);
        if (ok)   std::cout << "parse success\n";
        else      std::cerr << "parse failed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";

        if (f!=l) std::cerr << "trailing unparsed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
        return ok;
    } catch(const qi::expectation_failure<It>& e)
    {
        std::string frag(e.first, e.last);
        std::cerr << e.what() << "'" << frag << "'\n";
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer again. For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to NOT skip newlines so I can use them to separate instructions while still skipping newlines in certain places. I have tried this gr_newline idea, changing skip grammars with skip(), and a few other things, but it always ended up way too convoluted and probably also buggy. I think I'll take some time to look at your post and try to figure out a new way to skip the newlines in certain places.

Comment: Btw, I based all my stuff on the MiniC sample that comes with Qi, including the skipper.

Comment: @namezero Use `qi::blank` instead of `qi::space` as the skipper? Also, `qi::eol` already matches newlines.

Comment: @namezero Anyways, the skipper wasn't the question here. So, I'd say, don't change it. I'm just showing my take on it to _demonstrate_ that the `gr_label` rule compiles nicely.

Comment: Well I gues it came down to that :) But thatnks, eol is perfect and that way I don't need gr_newline. It seems to work somewhat now, I appreciate your example!