# Make Boost.Spirit parser to skip all spaces

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
int main ()
{
    std::string input("   aaa   ");
    std::string::iterator strbegin = input.begin();
    std::string p;
    qi::phrase_parse(strbegin, input.end(),
            qi::lexeme[+qi::char_],
            qi::space,                  
            p);                               

    std::cout << p << std::endl;
    std::cout << p.size() << std::endl;
}
```

In this code parser assigns `"aaa    "` to `p`. Why doesn't it skip all spaces? I expect `p` to be `"aaa"`. How it can be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking Spirit to emit the spaces with `qi::lexeme`. Compare: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/directive/lexeme.html

The rule `+(qi::char_ - qi::space)` should do.

Comment: Many more options to control skipping are described here http://stackoverflow.com/a/10469726/85371. Also, `qi::graph` should be equivalent to `char_ - space` AFAIR